# inequality for the zeta function for real $s$

Tags: inequality, zeta-functions

I am wondering why $\zeta(s)<1+\frac{1}{2^s}+(s-1)^{-1} 2^{-s+1}$ for $s>1.$
I was able to show that $\zeta(s) \leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}}$ but thats a much bigger upper bound.
Does someone have a hint ?

Comment: Why does the inequality come from? Why do you think that it holds?

Comment: which  inequality do you mean ? the one in the question or the one i was able to show?

Comment: The one that you want to show.